# Spring jpa:inbound-channel-adapter configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-integration

I  try to use multiple jpa:inbound-channel-adapter. However I have a problem. When I add two inbound-channel-adapter only last one works. For example there are two inbound channel we call  them x and y  for now. If I write  first x then y to application.xml file, only y works. If write first y then x only x works. Here is xml configuration,

```
    <int:channel id="emailChannel" />
<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter
    channel="emailChannel" entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory"
    auto-startup="true"
    jpa-query="select slt from Email slt where  slt.mailStatus = 'NEW'"
    expect-single-result="false" delete-after-poll="false">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="10000" >  
        <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRED"
            transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    </int:poller>
</int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>
<int:service-activator    input-channel="emailChannel" ref="EmailSenderEndPoint" method="sendEmail" />  


<int:channel id="msgChannel" />
<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter 
    channel="msgChannel" entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory"
    auto-startup="true"
    jpa-query="select rm from Msg rm where  rm.isApproved= '1' "
    expect-single-result="false" delete-after-poll="false">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="30000"> 
        <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRED"
            transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    </int:poller>
</int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>
<int:service-activator  input-channel="msgChannel" ref="MsgSenderEndPoint" method="sendMsg" />
```

In above example, only msgChannel works. But If I change like below, only emailChannel works.

```
    <int:channel id="msgChannel" />
<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter 
    channel="msgChannel" entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory"
    auto-startup="true"
    jpa-query="select rm from Msg rm where  rm.isApproved= '1' "
    expect-single-result="false" delete-after-poll="false">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="30000"> 
        <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRED"
            transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    </int:poller>
</int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>
<int:service-activator  input-channel="msgChannel" ref="MsgSenderEndPoint" method="sendMsg" />


<int:channel id="emailChannel" />
<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter
    channel="emailChannel" entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory"
    auto-startup="true"
    jpa-query="select slt from Email slt where  slt.mailStatus = 'NEW'"
    expect-single-result="false" delete-after-poll="false">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="10000" >  
        <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRED"
            transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    </int:poller>
</int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>
<int:service-activator    input-channel="emailChannel" ref="EmailSenderEndPoint" method="sendEmail" />
```

I cant understand what the problem is. Could you help me?

Edit : I solved the problem. I add interfaces to  service-activator classes then the problem solved.

Comment: What is the Spring Integration version, please?

Answer (score 0):

OK. This is a bug. See JIRA: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4325.

So, fix your problem you have to define unique `id` for those `<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>` definitions:

```
<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter id="msgJpaAdapter"
channel="msgChannel" entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory"

...

<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter id="emailJpaAdapter"
channel="emailChannel" entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory"
```

**UPDATE**

We have a test case for config:

```
<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter id="jpaInboundChannelAdapter1"
        entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory"
        entity-class="org.springframework.integration.jpa.test.entity.StudentDomain"
        expect-single-result="true"
        parameter-source="jpaParameterSource"
        channel="out">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
</int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter id="jpaInboundChannelAdapter2"
    entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory"
    entity-class="org.springframework.integration.jpa.test.entity.StudentDomain"
    max-results="13"
    delete-after-poll="true"
    flush-after-delete="true"
    channel="out">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
</int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

like:

```
    JpaExecutor jpaExecutor1 = context.getBean("jpaInboundChannelAdapter1.jpaExecutor", JpaExecutor.class);
    JpaExecutor jpaExecutor2 = context.getBean("jpaInboundChannelAdapter2.jpaExecutor", JpaExecutor.class);
    assertNotNull(jpaExecutor1);
    assertNotNull(jpaExecutor2);

    assertNotSame(jpaExecutor1, jpaExecutor2);
```

But in case of empty `id` they are indeed the same object.

Comment: I defined id but it couldn't helped me. Only solution I found that add interface to service-activator reference class.

Comment: Do you use different Ids for different channel Adapter definitions?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.